# Scripts_for_GB error: number of input seqs differ (aa: 0; nuc: 2)!! and Possible precedence issue with control flow operato

Tags: conda, bioperl

I am trying to calculate ka and ks, so I am using the test data available here: https://github.com/qiao-xin/Scripts_for_GB

Howerver,I have an error:

perl calculate_Ka_Ks_pipe.pl -d data/Ath.cds -g data/Ath.tandem.pairs -o result/Ath.td.kaks

Possible precedence issue with control flow operator at /home/dayana/miniconda3/envs/kaks/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/Bio/DB/IndexedBase.pm line 805.

ERROR: number of input seqs differ (aa: 0;  nuc: 2)!!

aa  ''
nuc 'AT1G30410.1 AT1G30420.1'
ERROR -- tmpdir-axt-converter-1194715-1690207616/c1.pep.aln -- File size is zero!!! at fa_prepareDATA4_kaks_calculator.pl line 190.

I would be happy if someone can help me.

Dayana.

I have no idea of the source of the problem.